# How does the Pack Alpha perk from Nuka World work?

Tags: fallout-4

The perk description states:

Your damage resistance is greatly increased (25% less damage) and you deal more damage (25%) while unarmed or using melee weapons.

Does it increase the damage resistance by 25% or reduce the damage you receive by 25% (like the Lone Wanderer perk)?

How does it stack with Lone Wanderer rank 2 and Attack Dog rank 4?

Is the damage and damage resistance bonus active while using your fists?

Answer (score 1):

From [this guide](http://www.carls-fallout-4-guide.com/nuka-world/faction-perks-benefits.php):

> Pack Alpha is quite an interesting Perk, particularly for melee builds as it gives you a 25% bonus to melee and unarmed damage. However, its secondary function is to provide increased damage resistance. **This is not a flat amount, it actually takes incoming damage from energy/physical effects and reduces it by 25%.** On top of your armor, this can be a huge bonus and may interest even non-melee players. Only problem is having to buddy up to The Pack!

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

Thus, it looks like incoming damage is just reduced by a quarter before it is applied.

As for how it stacks with Lone Wanderer 2 or Attack Dog 4, I believe the perks will stack with Pack Alpha, simply based on the way other perks stack on top of each other.

As to if it the bonus is active while using your fists, technically, yes, according to the description you posted:

> Your damage resistance is greatly increased (25% less damage) and you deal more damage (25%) ***while unarmed*** or using melee weapons.

However, going back to the other guide, see this sentence:

> On top of your armor, this can be a huge bonus and may interest even non-melee players.

Thus, the damage resistance is applied regardless of what weapon you are using (if any at all).

Comment: So the player can get up to 65% incoming damage reduction with all three perks if the resistances are additive. That's  interesting, too bad the Disciples don't have that perk instead.

Comment: @SkyHiRider I think the author of the guide shares the same sentiment (given the last part of the passage)

Comment: @Vemonus see to me when it says ***while unarmed***, I think that part only applies to the damage part.  Fallout has never been good at wording its perk descriptions... I'm trying to find out if this is the case.

Comment: @TimmyJim, the guide I posted actually explained it, I just realized

Comment: I think if Bethesda added a comma after the (25% less damage), it would be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I want to say that the damage resistance is the same as the Lone Wanderer perk.  The description for the Pack Alpha perk on [the wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Pack_Alpha) says:

> Your damage resistance is greatly increased (25% less damage) and you deal more damage (25%) while unarmed or using melee weapons.

I believe this is also the game description as well.  If you look at the [Lone Wanderer](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Lone_Wanderer_(perk)) perk, the description also says a % less damage.  For example, the level 1 description is:

> Who needs friends, anyway? When adventuring without a companion, you take 15% less damage and carry weight increases by 50.

As you can see, it says 15% less damage, just like how the Pack Alpha perk says 25% less damage.  That would lead me to say that having the level 2 version of the Lone Wanderer perk, it would stack to 55%.  Adding the 10% from Attack Dog 4 would bring it up to 65%.

As for the dealing more damage part, you can either use your fist or any melee weapon to get the bonus.  Based on the way the description is worded, it sounds like the damage resistance is passive and is always in effect (you don't need to use your fist/a melee weapon to get the damage resistance bonus).

Comment: Would be best to test this ingame and see the numbers before and after adding the perk via console. Too bad survival has the console disabled. You could give a settler a weapon that does 100 base damage, aggro him and check your health before and after taking all three perks.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have the ability to use the console either since I am on Xbox One. I also don't have some of the perks mentioned to test it with.

Comment: I'm on PC but if I enable the console via a mod I wont be able to get the last two achievements. And I don't want to mess with difficulty settings as I have no idea what it will do to my other saves.